# Forgot my Gmail password and SIM card - how can I recover my password?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I have forgotten my Gmail password and have lost my phone SIM card.

How can I recover access to my email account?

Answer (score 2):

There is the option to

> Confirm access to my recovery email: user@example.com (Alternate EMail ID)

See:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Through [Google Account Recovery](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery) you can recover your password by providing a range of details (such as account creation date, frequent contacts, label names, etc.). I've done it several times and out of 4 times it worked twice (the other times I didn't know enough information). The last time was about a month ago so likely the system didn't change since then.

Work your way through the first or third option, it should be somewhere in there.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is remember your SIM card number, Google will ask you for it.