# Recover Gmail password using Google Apps admin user

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, account-recovery

I'm not sure if this is the best site to ask this question so sorry in advance.

Last year I bought a domain and I created a Gmail account and registered the domain in Google Apps. Now I don't remember the password for the gmail account (@gmail.com) but I have access to Google Apps using the admin user (me@domain.com). Is there a way to recover this password using this user? If not, is there other way?

Comment: Have you already gone through the basic [gmail password recovery](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2943007?hl=en&rd=1) steps (e.g. secondary email account etc.)?

Comment: Related: [Forget my gmail password & SIM card - how can I recover my password?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42975/forget-my-gmail-password-sim-cardhow-can-i-recover-my-password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps and domain administrator account is irrelevant. You need to use gmail's forgotten password process to recover your passwork, as listed above.   Just keep trying, some people report rememebering enough details after the 3rd or 4th try.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this problem in the future be sure to set up alternate methods such as [Recover Gmail Passwords Via SMS](http://technohackzs.blogspot.com/2012/03/recover-gmail-passwords-via-sms-by.html) (note: article is also the source of the screenshots I've used below)

**1** To recover your Gmail password go to login to your gmail account and click *Can't access your account*

[image: Can't access your account Gmail]

**2** You'll then be able to submit the Gmail address for which you are trying to recover your password

[image: Forgot your password submit email address Gmail]

**3 & 4** Following a Captcha code verification you will be able to select your preferred method through which you can reset your password: SMS, secondary email or security question

[image: Gmail password recovery options]

Comment: I've tried that but Google ask me for the last password that I remember. I've had only one so I can't do anything with that form.

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía not even with the security question? I know you need the last-known password to recover *without* the security questions but I didn't think it was necessary if you had those Qs in place...

Comment: That image is a little old. Now Google ask for the creation date (I know it), the last time accesed (I know it too) and the last password that I remember (only one, so I don't have any idea).

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía just went through it again- I see what you're saying. Did you try RonSwansonsPyramidofGreatness? (kidding, obviously) Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: Lol xD Thank you anyway ^^ Do you know if there is a way to contact Google in a more verbose form? I would like to explain my problem.

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía not 100% sure, but rumor has it they'll [charge you 30¢ to reset your password](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/iyvJ8Kh13UU)